# The stochastic approximation algorithm of Robbins-Monro

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-approximation

I am reading [A Stochastic Approximation Method](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2236626) by Herbert Robbins and Sutton Monro and have a question concerning their algorithm. In below, I will basically follow their construction but will change some of their notations. For example, I will use uppercase letter for random variables and lowercase for real numbers. Please let me know if I intepretated the paper incorrecly or if there are any typos:

Let $M(x)$ be a real function and our goal is to approximate the root of $M(x)=\alpha$, assuming its uniqueness.

Suppose each $x\in \mathbb R$ corresponds a random variable $Y=Y(x)$ with distribution function

$$\mathbb P[Y(x)\le y]=H(y|x),$$

such that

$$M(x) = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} y dH(y|x)$$

is the expected value of $Y$ for the given $x$. Namely $M(x) = \mathbb E[Y(x)]$

Let $\{ a_n \}$ be a fixed sequence of real numbers such that $\sum a_n^2 < \infty$. Now we construct a sequence of random variables as follows: Let $X_1$ be an arbitrary constant and define:

$$X_{n+1}-X_{n} = a_n (\alpha - Y_n),$$

where $Y_n$ is a random variable such that

$$\mathbb P([Y_n \le y]|X_n) = H(y|X_n)$$

Now my question is: why does such $Y_n$ exist in this situation? And if possible, how to construct $Y_n$ explicitly?

(In general, given a sigma-algebra $\mathscr{F}$ and a random variable $Z$, there may not always exist a random variable $Y$ such that $\mathbb E[Y|\mathscr{F}]=Z$, right?)